# How to add a property to a PNG file

Tags: c#, .net, png, file-properties

I have a PNG file to which I want to add the properties

1. Pixels per unit, X axis
2. Pixels per unit, Y axis
3. Unit specifier:  meters

These properties are explained in the PNG specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html

I have  programmatically read the properties of the `.png` to check if the properties exists, so that I can set the value for this properties, but I could not see this properties in the `.png` file.
(Refer pixel-per-unit.JPG)

How can we add properties to the `.png` file?

regards
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using [pngcs](https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/) library (you need to rename the downloaded dll to "pngcs.dll")

I needed to add some custom text properties, but you can easily do much more.

Here is my implementation for adding custom text properties:

```
using Hjg.Pngcs;  // https://code.google.com/p/pngcs/
using Hjg.Pngcs.Chunks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MarkerGenerator.Utils
{
    class PngUtils
    {

        public string getMetadata(string file, string key)
        {

            PngReader pngr = FileHelper.CreatePngReader(file);
            //pngr.MaxTotalBytesRead = 1024 * 1024 * 1024L * 3; // 3Gb!
            //pngr.ReadSkippingAllRows();
            string data = pngr.GetMetadata().GetTxtForKey(key);
            pngr.End();
            return data; ;
        }


        public static void addMetadata(String origFilename, Dictionary<string, string> data)
        {
            String destFilename = "tmp.png";
            PngReader pngr = FileHelper.CreatePngReader(origFilename); // or you can use the constructor
            PngWriter pngw = FileHelper.CreatePngWriter(destFilename, pngr.ImgInfo, true); // idem
            //Console.WriteLine(pngr.ToString()); // just information
            int chunkBehav = ChunkCopyBehaviour.COPY_ALL_SAFE; // tell to copy all 'safe' chunks
            pngw.CopyChunksFirst(pngr, chunkBehav);          // copy some metadata from reader 
            foreach (string key in data.Keys)
            {
                PngChunk chunk = pngw.GetMetadata().SetText(key, data[key]);
                chunk.Priority = true;
            }

            int channels = pngr.ImgInfo.Channels;
            if (channels < 3)
                throw new Exception("This example works only with RGB/RGBA images");
            for (int row = 0; row < pngr.ImgInfo.Rows; row++)
            {
                ImageLine l1 = pngr.ReadRowInt(row); // format: RGBRGB... or RGBARGBA...
                pngw.WriteRow(l1, row);
            }
            pngw.CopyChunksLast(pngr, chunkBehav); // metadata after the image pixels? can happen
            pngw.End(); // dont forget this
            pngr.End();
            File.Delete(origFilename);
            File.Move(destFilename, origFilename);

        }

        public static void addMetadata(String origFilename,string key,string value)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            data.Add(key, value);
            addMetadata(origFilename, data);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [SetPropertyItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem.aspx). You can find the property ids [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id.aspx)

You would use the property id to get and then set the property item for your meta-data.

**EDIT**

The three id's that you need (I think) are:

1. 0x5111 - Pixel Per Unit X
2. 0x5112 - Pixel Per Unit Y
3. 0x5110 - Pixel Unit